# how to achieve bytecode instrumentation on the fly

Tags: aspectj, instrumentation, java-bytecode-asm, javassist, bytecode-manipulation

what are the available technologies we have to implement instrumentation on the fly. Till now, i have worked on some aspectj and javassits for bytecode instrumentation.

Comment: I have voted to close this question because it is too broad (and I am not the only one who voted). BTW, Vimlesh, AspectJ instrumentation also works on the fly via LTW. There is also an API which enables you to do it manually during runtime without the weaving agent.

Comment: First, you have to decide whether you want to know how to process byte code of classes (aka bytecode manipulation) or whether you want to know how to update classes on the fly (aka Instrumentation) or whether you are searching for libraries offering both together. And then you may consider that all of these questions are off-topic as we are not a tutorial or library searching facility.

Comment: Holger, Here 'instrumentation on the fly' means change the already instrumented code when process is in running. Example when System is coming up you have weaved com.foo.bar..* package and at runtime when process is in running from sometime and you wants to add waving for com.foo.weaveme..* and disbale weaving of com.foo.bar..*. weaving should happen without restarting the pocess.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my library [Byte Buddy](https://github.com/raphw/byte-buddy) which allows you to define a Java agent quite easily which hooks into Java's class loading procedure.

Generally, it depends on what you need to do for deciding which approach fits best. Javassist and Byte Buddy operate at runtime. AspectJ requires a different compiler what many consider heavy weight. For a tutorial on Byte Buddy, look at [the webpage](https://bytebudddy.net).